# "go get gRPC" fails with "network is unreachable" error

Tags: go, grpc

When I run `go get google.golang.org/grpc` I get the error `error network is unreachable` but `ping google.com` is working. The full error is:

```
go_project imports
    google.golang.org/grpc imports
    google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport tested by
    google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.test imports
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/errdetails: google.golang.org/genproto@v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013: Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/proxy-golang-org-prod/80a959b15da3a0d9-google.golang.org:genproto-v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013.zip?
Expires=1659594855&GoogleAccessId=gcs-urlsigner-prod%40golang-modproxy.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=f1Aa6%2Bao%2BUgQgRvqn3ijWO7JwJCtPwNv1MM34XdhSfb4EixWlrB6kyZjbMvN%2Bt6o%2B6i2CkNaIiNCGDjr0vUUmc6HBIjWbs55dZXxhP4QgNR2S4VfAzrsuIqrUUPCNp%2BeIL6BLwJbLOHCqpUVR3gwK1qwVth9h7fhn8cDR9FmSVWNIIGcr0UMiCULsVJAIcJAGSH28vwja93ckiCz5kFqe6qV4F8dXbhvc8QXzMCc9p9l1ABXaH3McZdFF9SPK8vJsrDLNqA2NR3SCFZIkQzLU52iyauDgDP%2FccbK38juAWkMK07DOutPNjk45%2BUJu%2B%2B2qwA%2B5kcudcIo2xeA9dTJ7A%3D%3D":
 dial tcp [2404:6800:4009:82d::2010]:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

Screenshot below shows error (as above):

[image: screenshot showing error]

Comment: google.com and google.golang,org are totally different hosts

Comment: ping google.golang.org -> is working fine

Comment: Is your system configured to allow the go binary to access the internet?

Comment: It looks like you are unable to reach `storage.googleapis.com` (which resolves to `2404:6800:4009:82d::2010`, amongst other IP's, and probably only from India). This appears to be up as far as I can tell. A `traceroute6 2404:6800:4009:82d::2010` may provide more info.